# How to partially replace a string in a column pandas Dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  Name          Comment
1 Ama           Delay with coming home client to provide place he visited
2 Kofi          Enquiry on apples client to provide refund 
3 Kwame         Equiry on tables client advised with enquiry
4 Theo          Emotional challenge client to provide details
5 Isaiah        Eating on empty stomach client to confirm the issues
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
  Name          Comment
1 Ama           Delay with coming home
2 Kofi          Enquiry on apples 
3 Kwame         Enquiry on tables 
4 Theo          Emotional challenge 
5 Isaiah        Eating on empty stomach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to deleted everything after "client", use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Comment'] = df['Comment'].str.replace(r'\s*\bclient\b.*', '',
                                          case=False, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
     Name                  Comment
1     Ama   Delay with coming home
2    Kofi        Enquiry on apples
3   Kwame         Equiry on tables
4    Theo      Emotional challenge
5  Isaiah  Eating on empty stomach
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Vr45S/1)

Regex:

```
\s*       # match 0 or more spaces
\b        # match word boundary
client    # match "client"
\b        # match word boundary
.*        # match anything until the end
```

##### excluding strings that start with "Client":

Use the same regex but add a look-behind to match a non-space: `(?<=\S)`

```
df['Comment'] = df['Comment'].str.replace(r'(?<=\S)\s*\bclient.*', '',
                                          case=False, regex=True)
```

Example:

```
     Name                   Comment
1     Ama    Delay with coming home
2    Kofi         Enquiry on apples
3   Kwame          Equiry on tables
4    Theo       Emotional challenge
5  Isaiah   Eating on empty stomach
6  Alfred  Client starting sentence
```

[reged demo](https://regex101.com/r/sH8RaY/1)

Comment: Yes i want to delete every thing after client unless the string does not start with "client"

Comment: Do you mean *"unless the string **does start** with client"*? See the update

Comment: if the string starts with client do not remove it. but if is in the middle of the string remove it and everything after it

Comment: @alfred check the updated part of my answer, this is doing that ;)

Comment: @alfred I see you picked the split+slicing answer, while it's a concise be aware that it's almost certainly less efficient as it chains 2 operations

Comment: I picked your response rather.

Comment: @alfred you don't have to, you can keep the other one as picked if you like it more (it is quite short after all), but just be aware of the difference

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = [['Ama', 'Delay with coming home client to provide place he visited'], 
        ['Kofi', 'Enquiry on apples client to provide refund '], 
        ['Kwame', 'Equiry on tables client advised with enquiry'], 
        ['Theo', 'Emotional challenge client to provide details'], 
        ['Isaiah', 'Eating on empty stomach client to confirm the issues'], 
        ['Amy', 'client is smart']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Comment'])
```

`df`

```
    Name    Comment
0   Ama     Delay with coming home client to provide place...
1   Kofi    Enquiry on apples client to provide refund
2   Kwame   Equiry on tables client advised with enquiry
3   Theo    Emotional challenge client to provide details
4   Isaiah  Eating on empty stomach client to confirm the ...
5   Amy     client is smart
```

---

**Code**

split by ' client' and take first

```
df['Comment'] = df['Comment'].str.split(' client').str[0]
```

`df`

```
    Name    Comment
0   Ama     Delay with coming home
1   Kofi    Enquiry on apples
2   Kwame   Equiry on tables
3   Theo    Emotional challenge
4   Isaiah  Eating on empty stomach
5   Amy     client is smart
```